# css align dynamic content vertically

Tags: html, css

I have two groups of dynamic content within a container that I am trying (unsuccessfully so far!) to align. Currently looks like:

https://ibb.co/DppP1SP

The problem is the titles are varying over 1 or 2 lines and throwing the rest of the layout out. I have tried using table display with my divs, and flex, and nothing has worked so far (I may not be doing it correctly).

I want the link, the excerpt text, and the byline (which are all fixed) to be aligned. I was trying to align it to the bottom, and keep the header as is (at the top).

The struture of the html (in a cms so at this stage I can't change it), is:

```
<article id="post-xyz">
   <div><img etc></div>
   <div class="text-container">
      <header>
         <h3>the Problem Title</h3>
         <div class="fixed-byline>etc</div>
      </header>
      <div class="wordcount-fixed-excerpt">
         <p>etc</p>
         <a>continue reading</a>
      </div>   (end excerpt)
   </div>  (end text)
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="fixed-byline">etc</div>
```

you have missing "